# Weird Windows 7 UI issues

Tags: windows, user-interface

I have some really weird and seemingly random Windows UI issues.. some parts of the UI are sometimes completely unresponsive (highlight animations are missing, nothing happens on click) such as the Windows taskbar, and some just behave in a weird way (when i click a tab on Google Chrome to select it, it deletes the tab.. I'm not sure how this could be related though, as Chrome has its own ui).

Some programs seem to suffer more from this than others. For example, NetBeans IDE doesnt seem to work at all and nothing happens when I click anything in the program. Firefox seems to work, but there is no way to resize the window. In some other programs I tested, resizing works.

CTRL+ALT+DEL and clicking "cancel" seems to fix the unresponsiveness of the taskbar for a moment, at least.

Anyone got a clue what could be causing these things?

Comment: Check your Task Manager to see if you can determine if any programs have high CPU load/RAM usage. Do you have a network and network locations that may attempting to be sync'd to Offline Files? Have you got an Anti-Virus running a scan in the background?